# java.util.Calendar set with zero seconds persists to mysql via jdbc with 1 second

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, calendar

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(1976, 8, 18, 5, 30, 0);
java.util.Date dt = cal.getTime();
//use jdbc to persist this to mysql
```

When we query back the value from mysql, we get the date (Note the extra second):
1976-08-18 05:30:**01**

After using a jdbc logging driver P6Spy (https://github.com/p6spy) we could see from that log that the insert statement correctly had the seconds set to zero.

Why is an extra second being added? NOTE: this doesn't happen every time. In fact, it happens about half the time.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a call to set the milliseconds:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(1976, 8, 18, 5, 30, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
java.util.Date dt = cal.getTime();
//use jdbc to persist this to mysql
```

In short, the milliseconds are being rounded up, either by the driver or by mysql itself. When you say Calendar.getInstance() it gets you an instance initialized with the current time, including milliseconds. When java displays the time by default, it truncates milliseconds (as well as the p6spy logger), but the database rounds the milliseconds to seconds. Thus, half the time it shows zero seconds and half the time it shows one second.